# Guardar datos desde un controlador y usarlos en otro - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo un **MVC** con **ASP NET Core 2** en **C#**. El modelo para Login ok:

Controlador:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await this.userHelper.LoginAsync(model);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (this.Request.Query.Keys.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
                {
                    return this.Redirect(this.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].First());
                }
                ViewData["Module"] = await this.moduleRepository.GetByIdAsync(model.ModuleId);
                ViewData["ModuleId"] = model.ModuleId;

                return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Lo que quiero es usar los valores guardados en `ViewData`, o en un `ViewBag`, o algo similar desde otro controlador. de hecho tan solo necesito valor `ModuleId` de forma global en la solución.

Comment: ¿Te has planteado usar [cookies](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/244904/cookies-in-asp-net) o [sesiones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Estoy provisionalmente trabajando con Cookies, con sesiones, ni idea. El problema es que quiero guardar objetos completos y los cookies no lo permiten, a menos que los serialize con json .... :)

Comment: En ese caso las sesiones te debería servir. En el enlace que te envié en el comentario anterior podrás ver como usarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías usar TempData.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CargamosDatos()
    {
            TempData["Clavedic"] = myobject;
    }



 public async Task<IActionResult> LeemosDatos()
    {
            if (TempData.Peek("Clavedic") is MyObject obj)
            {
             ... realizar acciones
            }
    }
```

Se debe tener algo en cuenta en el uso de este diccionario, una vez se haya llamado a "Peek", el objeto desaparece del diccionario, por lo que no será accesible si se vuelve a llamar al método "LeemosDatos". Si se quiere mantener se debe añadir la instruccion `TempData.Keep();`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LeemosDatos()
    {
            if (TempData.Peek(Clavedic) is MyObject obj)
            {
             ... realizar acciones
            }
            TempData.Keep();
    }
```

https://www.tiracodigo.com/index.php/programacion/mvc/formas-de-almacenar-datos-temporales-en-asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata-y-session

Comment: Es muy buena tu respuesta. Reconozco que no sabía la funcionalidad del TempData con Peek y Keep. Me parece simplemente "genial" por parte del equipo de desarrollo de ASP.NET MVC,

Answer (score 0):

Tienes **dos** opciones para solucionar tu problema, variables de **Sesión** o **Cookies**.

- **Variables de Sesión**:

En tu caso, almacena el valor de `ModuleId` en la sesión del usuario actual:

```
Session["ModuleId"] = model.ModuleId;
```

y en otro Controlador la recuperas:

```
var _moduleId = Session["ModuleId"];
```

- **Uso de Cookies:**

En tu Controlador principal creas una **Cookie** con el valor de `ModuleId`:

```
HttpCookie _moduleIdCookie = new HttpCookie("__ModuleId", model.ModuleId);
HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(_moduleIdCookie);
```

Y en el otro Controlador la recuperas:

```
var _cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["__ModuleId"];
var _moduleId = _cookie.Value;
```

En mi opinión, yo siempre optaría por utilizar **Cookies**. Y si en tu caso `ModuleId` contiene información sensible que quieres mantener oculta por seguridad, podrías encriptar el valor de la Cookie.

Te recomiendo el articulo [Encriptar y desencriptar cookies en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/9/19/encriptar-y-desencriptar-cookies-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-aspnet-mvc)